# jQuery each array index append to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to append the values of array I've made into another div but when I append the array value its appending all the values of the array not just the one I've added(by click), any suggestions would be great, thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div id="products">
    <ul>
        <li><p>Lorem 1</p><button class="target">Add</button></li>
        <li><p>Lorem 2</p><button class="target">Add</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="cart">
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var array = Array();

    $(".target").click(function() {

        array.push($(this).siblings('p').text());

        $.each(array, function(index, value) {

            $("#cart ul").append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
        });


    });
});
```

When I click Add on say the first button its displays

Lorem 1

but when I then click the add on the second button it displays

Lorem 1
Lorem 1
Lorem 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the items to the array, which makes sense if you want to keep a list of added items, but then you are looping through the array when adding items to the list, which will make it add all items to the items already existing there.

You can just add the last item:

```
array.push($(this).siblings('p').text());
$("#cart ul").append("<li>" + array[array.length - 1] + "</li>");
```

or you can clear the list before adding the items:

```
array.push($(this).siblings('p').text());
$("#cart ul").empty();
$.each(array, function(index, value) {
  $("#cart ul").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Guffa that makes sense, the [array.length - 1] is what I needed, thanks for you think and the well written explanation! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because you loop on each element of the array, so you get all your elements.
Try without the $.each in your click function, it will be better.

Comment: That makes sense but how would I get the value of my array then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only add one value when the selector `$(".target")` is clicked, you should do something like

```
  // assuming you want the last value in the array.
  var value = array[array.length-1]; // could also do $(this).siblings('p').text()
  $("#cart ul").append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
```

It seems like you might not even need your array, (unless it is being used by some other functions as well).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ipulem/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){

  var array = [];

  $(".target").click(function() {

     array.push( $(this).siblings('p').text() );
     $("#cart ul").append("<li>"+ array[array.length -1] +"</li>");

  });

});
```

Comment: Do you really want to re-add all of the items that are already in the list? If he is just adding one item per click, this function removes and adds the same list subset over and over.

Comment: Well, I mean redundant code is redundant no matter how many items are in the list. What if each element requires an AJAX request? There are many cases that could make this operation really expensive. It doesn't appear in this example, but for the sake of everyone else using this as a reference, it would be best not to be inefficient.

Comment: @Jlange you're perfectly right. Edited to reflect your comment